# Service providers block artisan optimize every time on composer update

Tags: laravel, composer-php, laravel-5

I pushed some changes to our repo and they auto-deployed to Forge. The deployment failed with this error:

```
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postInstall
> php artisan optimize


  [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]    
  Class 'MyRepo\MyPackage\MyServiceProvider' not found  


Script php artisan optimize handling the post-install-cmd event returned with error code 1
```

So I edited the `config/app.php` file to temporarily comment out that service provider line, then re-ran `composer update` without any problems to `artisan optimize` this time.

I then uncommented the service provider line and ran `artisan optimize` again to make sure all was well and got no errors.

Because the composer.lock file changed on Forge after this composer update, I pushed it to the repo.

This triggered yet another `artisan optimize` error for that same service provider. So I repeated my steps above.

Now **every single time** there is a new deploy from the repo, `artisan optimize` triggers that error on that service provider **even if we didn't add new service providers**.

If I simply run `composer update` then I'm right back with the same `artisan optimize` error as before.

Tried doing `composer clear-cache` but that didn't fix it.

I ran a test script to make sure that service provider is working and autoloaded as expected by calling the class it loads, so I've verified the PSR-4 namespace works just fine.

Here is my project composer.json:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "laravel"
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.0.0",
        "laravel/framework": "5.2.*",
        "laravel/cashier": "~6.0",
        "my-repo/my-package": "dev-master"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.6",
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~5",
        "phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects": "3.2.*@dev"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "classmap": [
            "tests/TestCase.php"
        ]
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "git",
            "url": "git@bitbucket.org:my-repo/my-package.git"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is our private package's composer.json:

```
{
    "name": "my-repo/my-package",
    "description": "My package.",
    "type": "package",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "illuminate/support": "5.2.*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "raveren/kint": "~1"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "MyRepo\\MyPackage\\": "src/"
        },
        "files": [
            "src/MyPackage/helpers.php"
        ]
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

Even if I change the project's composer.json to pull this by `{"type": "path", "url": "./library/my-repo"}` I get the same error.

It's as if the optimized class loader is cleared of private repo classes every time I run `composer update`.

I'm pretty stuck here.

Comment: `composer dump-autoload`?

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski yep, same issue still.

Comment: Do you have the configuration files cached (php artisan config:cache)? You can try running that again and it will clear and rebuild the cache or stop caching the config by running 'php artisan cache:clear'

Comment: @RobFonseca `cache:clear` just gives me the same service provider error. On another note, I'm seeing `[Studio] Loading path library/my-package` in the `composer update` output. We dropped the `studio` package from composer.json several commits ago and now it is spontaneously showing up again on staging. I've confirmed it still isn't in composer.json and cleared composer cache again...but it keeps loading.

Comment: Make sure it's up to psr4 standards.  The namespace should match the folder structure otherwise the autloader won't catch it.

Comment: @user3158900 it's PSR-4 and runs fine locally. I think the problem might be that I tried to use `franzl/studio` on staging and then removed it in favor of referencing the private repos within composer instead of symlinking. Something seems stuck.

Comment: So it wasn't studio that was doing it. Completely removed it from the equation and still having this problem of having to manually comment/uncomment the service provider of any private repos every time I run `composer update` so I can manually run `artisan optimize`. :(